# convert random input value to number for counter calculation

Tags: javascript, counter

I am having a small issue.

I am trying to build a counter and so far everything has worked fine. I wanted to add a last thing: an input field, so no matter which number the user types in, it will be processed and added to the counter and showed on the screen.

The only problem is that I don't get an integer, but a NaN and I have been struggling to convert it into a regular integer, but it seems not to be working.

```js
let numValue = document.getElementById('number-search').value;
let num = parseInt(numValue);

let add = document.getElementById('add');
let subtract = document.getElementById('subtract');

let int = document.getElementById('counter');
let counter = 0;

add.addEventListener('click', function() {
  counter += num;
  int.innerHTML = counter;
})
```

```html
<p id="counter">0</p>
<input type="number" id="number-search" class="number-search" placeholder="Type your number here" autocomplete="off" />
<span>
  <button id="add" placeholder="">ADD</button>
</span>
<span>
  <button id="subtract" placeholder="">SUBTRACT</button>
</span>
```

I am using Vanilla Javascript. How can I get an integer to be summed to the counter and showed on screen?

Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

```js
let numValue = document.getElementById('number-search').value;
let num = parseInt(numValue);

let add = document.getElementById('add');
let subtract = document.getElementById('subtract');

let int = document.getElementById('counter');
let counter = 0;

add.addEventListener('click', function() {
let numValue = parseInt(document.getElementById('number-search').value);
let counterValue = parseInt(document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML);
  counterValue += numValue;
  document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML=counterValue;
})
```

```html
<p id="counter">0</p>
<input type="number" id="number-search" class="number-search" placeholder="Type your number here" autocomplete="off" />
<span>
  <button id="add" placeholder="">ADD</button>
</span>
<span>
  <button id="subtract" placeholder="">SUBTRACT</button>
</span>
```

You shouldn't use globals in your event listener. There is no telling when they may be modified.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert value inside `click` function by extracting the value from search field and then doing `parseInt`:

```js
let add = document.getElementById('add');
let subtract = document.getElementById('subtract');

let int = document.getElementById('counter');
let counter = 0;

add.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
  const { value = '0' } = document.getElementById('number-search');
  const numericValue = parseInt(value);
  counter += numericValue;
  int.textContent = counter;
})
```

```html
<p id="counter">0</p>
<input type="number" id="number-search" class="number-search" placeholder="Type your number here" autocomplete="off" />
<span>
  <button id="add" placeholder="">ADD</button>
</span>
<span>
  <button id="subtract" placeholder="">SUBTRACT</button>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're getting the value of the input field on initial load and not when the add button is clicked.

Due to this, when the button is clicked, the value in `num` empty which will give you NaN.

Also, it is good to have a check if input field has a value.

```js
let numEl = document.getElementById('number-search');

let add = document.getElementById('add');
let subtract = document.getElementById('subtract');

let int = document.getElementById('counter');
let counter = 0;

add.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const num = numEl.value ? parseInt(numEl.value, 10): 0;
  counter += num;
  int.innerHTML = counter;
})
```

```html
<p id="counter">0</p>
<input type="number" id="number-search" class="number-search" placeholder="Type your number here" autocomplete="off" />
<span>
  <button id="add" placeholder="">ADD</button>
</span>
<span>
  <button id="subtract" placeholder="">SUBTRACT</button>
</span>
```

Comment: Thank you guyz. I tried with the first one and it worked fine. Thank a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `num.value` within your add function, because otherwise it will have a constant value. Then, you need to convert that `num.value` to a number:

```js
let num = document.getElementById('number-search');

let add = document.getElementById('add');
let subtract = document.getElementById('subtract');

let int = document.getElementById('counter');
let counter = 0;

add.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(num.value);
  counter += Number(num.value);
  int.innerHTML = counter;
})
```

```html
<p id="counter">0</p>
<input type="number" id="number-search" class="number-search" placeholder="Type your number here" autocomplete="off" />
<span>
  <button id="add" placeholder="">ADD</button>
</span>
<span>
  <button id="subtract" placeholder="">SUBTRACT</button>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let num=()=>parseInt(document.getElementById('number-search').value) //you had a static value of "" that you tried to change to number.. that's y NaN occurs

let add = document.getElementById('add');
let subtract = document.getElementById('subtract');

let int = document.getElementById('counter');
let counter = 0;

add.addEventListener('click', function() {
  counter += num();
  int.innerHTML = counter;
})

subtract.addEventListener('click', function(){
  counter -= num();
  int.innerHTML = counter;
})
```

```html
<p id="counter">0</p>
<input type="number" id="number-search" class="number-search" placeholder="Type your number here" autocomplete="off" />
<span>
  <button id="add" placeholder="">ADD</button>
</span>
<span>
  <button id="subtract" placeholder="">SUBTRACT</button>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :-)

```js
let counter = 0
 actionPerform =(value)=> {

let numValue = document.getElementById('number-search').value
let num = parseInt(numValue)

let add = document.getElementById('add')
let subtract = document.getElementById('subtract')

let int = document.getElementById('counter')
if(value === 'ADD'){
  counter = counter + num 
}else{
 counter = counter - num 
}

  int.innerHTML = counter
  
}
```

```html
<p id="counter">0</p>
<input type="number" id="number-search" class="number-search" placeholder="Type your number here" autocomplete="off" />
<span>
  <button id="add" placeholder="" onclick="actionPerform('ADD')">ADD</button>
</span>
<span>
  <button id="subtract"onclick="actionPerform('SUBTRACT')" placeholder="">SUBTRACT</button>
</span>
```